# SQL Update, Space inbetween a Postcode

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-update

i need to do an update query on a postcode field to create a space between. E.g is there are 7 characters e.g `HP114GT` i want to have `HP11 4GT` or if there are 6 e.g `HP14GT` i want `HP1 4GT`. any help would be great!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Storing it with no spaces tends to make it easier to search over - could you not just insert a space where you think it best when you *present* this information to your users?

Comment: We have updated the form to include the space, but this is to correct data that has already been entered. we use SQL Server

Comment: Any answer for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = CASE WHEN LEN(Column) = 6 THEN STUFF(Column, 4, 0, ' ')
                  WHEN LEN(Column) = 7 THEN STUFF(Column, 5, 0, ' ')
             END
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', Column, 1) = 0
      AND LEN(Column) BETWEEN 6 AND 7
```

Comment: i have tried this and it has worked, but it hasnt worked on all the records even though they match the criteria? do you no why this might be?

Comment: It could be that the string contain trailing spaces. Try with `CHARINDEX(' ', RTRIM(Column), 1) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Col=LEFT(Col, len(Col)-3)+' '+RIGHT(col, 3)
WHERE LEN(Col)>3 AND
CHARINDEX(' ',  Col, 1)=0
```

Comment: thank you for you, will i have to run this seperately for 6 or 7 digits? or can i run one update that will do both at the same time?

Comment: ok thank you, i have alot of data that already has spaces and some american postcodes which are numbers? will it also put an extra space in them??

Comment: Yes, It will add an extra space! To avoid that add one more condition in where to ignore such records (AND CHARINDEX(' ',  Col, 1)=0)).

Comment: Thank you, im quite new to SQL could you explain in laymans terms what the query is doing? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle I would do something like:

```
Update mytable 
    set pin_code = DECODE 
    (LENGTH(pin_code),7,SUBSTR(pin_code,1,4)||' '||SUBSTR(pin_code,5,7),6,SUBSTR(pin_code,1,3)||' '||SUBSTR(pin_code,4,6));
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL this works. Probably in other DBMS also, since the functions are more or less the same usually.

```
update your_table set col = replace(col, right(col, 3), concat(' ', right(col, 3)))
where char_length(col) > 3;
```